# Open a form in panel from another form and closing existing form winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have issue With form control in c#, I Main form that has navigation buttons it, each opens a different form. That  part works fine

```
FRMBanner Banner = new FRMBanner();
Banner.TopLevel = false;
panel2.Controls.Add(Banner);
Banner.Show();
Banner.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
Banner.BringToFront();
```

the issues I have is how do I work out what form has been opened and close it. The only way I could work out how to do it was put a timer on each form and check it the public static bool is true or false and if it was false it would just invoke this.close();  on the page, I know there must be an easier way to do this any help would be great.

Comment: can you explain more what is the scenario and why you want to check that

Comment: Create a list<string> on your main form and when you open form add to list as well and when you close remove that from list

Comment: Just add those controls to a list and loop through that list to see which are opened.

Comment: With TopLevel set the *false*, the form turns into a plain control, not significantly different from a UserControl.  You don't "close" it anymore, just like you don't "close" a button, if it needs to be unloaded then you must call its Dispose() method.  Storing the reference so you can do this properly is a very generic programming task that doesn't have anything to do with the fact that it is a class derived from Form.  Create a UserControl instead as long as you're struggling with OOP.

Comment: how do i close a form from a list I added the  List<Form1> _forms = new List<Form1>();  and then in the button i added the  _forms.Add(Banner);  foreach (var form in _forms)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(form.ToString());
               form.Close();
            }

Comment: List<Control> _forms = new List<Control>(); that all it needed to be and added   foreach (var form in _forms)
            {               
                form.Dispose();
                         } that seems to do the trick thanks for your kelp

Comment: that did not work form.Dispose(); with control list does not unload the forms - scratch that i needed to clear the list it does help